# "Need to do something" versus "need doing something"

Tags: phrase-choice

[The OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/need) shows that *need* can be used as "need to do something" and as "need doing something." The examples shown by the dictionary are, among others, the following ones:

> He needs to win this game to stay in the match.
>   This shirt needs to be washed.
>   This shirt needs washing.

Could I rewrite the first sentence as follows?

> He needs winning this game to stay in the match.

Does the sentence have the same meaning as the first one, or do those sentences have a (slightly) different meaning?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["need + verb-ing" vs "need + \[to be\] + verb-ed"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/need-verb-ing-vs-need-to-be-verb-ed) (OP's "rewrite" sentence is totally unacceptable, btw).

Comment: I voted to close this question, but the other question doesn't explain why "He needs winning this game to stay in the match." is not an acceptable rephrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English grammar books say that

> He needs *winning* this game to stay in the ...

is not appropriate because there *winning* doesn't express a passive infinitive as in

> The sofa needs *cleaning* again.

Strictly speaking, your sentence doesn't make sense if you replace *winning* with "to be won", while "The sofa needs *to be cleaned* again" does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your shoes. (You must do this)
Your shoes need to be cleaned. (More focus on the shoes, not the agent)
Your shoes need cleaning. (Implies that YOU should clean them. Often mothers and spouses use this structure and raise their eyebrows or tut impatiently)
Other instances in which we can see this:
Your bedroom  needs tidying.
The car needs cleaning.
Notice that the second person (you) is omnipresent here, unlike other passive forms.

Look out for "wants doing" too.
:)

Answer (score 0):

in active sentences we use need to do something  while in passive we use need doing. 
I need to cleen my shoes.
my shoes need cleaning.

Comment: Please provide explanations with your answers. This seems to repeat what the dictionary says.

Answer (score -1):

In the OALD "need doing something" example, the "doing something" is "washing". As in
 "This shirt needs washing." If the subject is singular, then use "needs".

If the subject is plural use "need". As in "The geese need feeding."

You can follow need/needs with a gerund (a verb ending in -ing), but you would not inject a word between need/needs and the gerund.

Comment: Does "He needs winning this game to stay in the match." have the same meaning "He needs to win this game to stay in the match." has?

Comment: @kiamlaluno "He needs winning this game to stay in the match" is not proper grammar. Can't think of how to explain why at the moment, so I'll leave that to someone else to answer, but it isn't correct.

Comment: @kiamlaluno On the other hand, "He is needing to win this game to stay in the match" *is* perfectly correct.

Comment: @WendiKidd I was pointing that this answer is not saying what I am asking. I know that _needs_ is for the third person singular, and that is not what I am asking. Your comment says what I am asking.

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: I must say *"He is needing to win this game..."* doesn't work for me as a Brit. It sounds like "Indian English".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. I'd definitely say "He needs to win..." but I thought "He is needing..." would be correct if it was happening right now. Maybe not. I need to research this more, I should be able to explain the reasons behind this instead of just what sounds right to me.

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: [This ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/25406/2637) suggests *I am needing* is always incorrect. I wouldn't go that far, but I agree [this TOEFL Prep for Chinese Speakers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22need+money+not+I+am+needing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). **Avoid present continuous with "emotional/judgemental" words** is sound advice - we don't normally say *"I am liking you"*, for example. On the other hand, you can say *"I am enjoying this meal"*, so there are no fixed "rules" involved. Just (well-established) idiomatic preferences.

Comment: American speakers would never say _He is needing to win_ in any sentence. They would say _He needs to win_. It is the combination of _is needing to_ that sounds wrong. It would be OK, but unusual, to say _He is needing a win_.